# Who hit the Nile with his stick?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, beshalach, va-eira

[שמות יז ה](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%96_%D7%94) has:

> ומטך אשר הכית בו את היאור

Moshe did not hit the Nile river, Aharon did. (See [שמות ז יט, with Rashi](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%96_%D7%99%D7%98).) Why does the Torah say otherwise?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

אמר רבי אבהו כל המעשה את חבירו לדבר מצוה מעלה עליו הכתיב כאילו עשאה שנאמר ומטך אשר הכית בו את היאר וכי משה הכהו והלא אהרן הכהו אלא לאמר לך כל המעשה את חבירו לדבר מצוה מעלה עליו הכתיב כאילו עשאה

סנהדרין צ״ט׃

The Gemara says that whoever encourages his friend to do a Mitzva the Posuk considers it as if he did it since it says "And your stick which you hit with it the river" did Moshe hit it, Aaron hit it? This comes to teach us that whoever encourages his friend to do a Mitzva it is as if he did it.

We learn from here the Halacha of Shliach Shel Adam Kemoso.